# Javascript wont execute

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have JavaScript which gets the current users emails and then redirects the user to a new page with the email when client clicks on an ASPLinkButton. But the issue is since having this I can't edit the page where this JavaScript is, the ribbon is grayed out. Here is the code I am using

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData,"sp.js");   
var context = null;   
var web = null;   
var currentUser = null;   

function getWebUserData() 
{   
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();   
    web = context.get_web();   
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();   
    currentUser.retrieve();   
    context.load(web);   
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));   
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
    window.location="http://servername/Sysomos%20Login/default.aspx?user="+ userObject.get_email();
}
```

as you can see I have the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData,"sp.js")` so that the function can execute but this greys out the ribbon, if I was to switch this to `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("sp.js",getWebUserData)` then the function will not execute when I click the link.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the ribbon greys out when there's an error in some javascript. Without being able to find an error in your javascript, can you ensure it in fact is correct? At least syntactically...